# Extbase: Sorting got mixed when using 1:n on same model

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have a Model that has a 1:n relation to itself (A Product can have multiple Sub-Products).

When updating a entry of this model (the parent), the sorting of all other Products got mixed up.

TCA of the sub:

```
sub_product' => [
   'exclude' => true,
   'label' => 'SubProduct',
   'config' => [
      'type' => 'inline',
      'foreign_table' => 'tx_gbform_domain_model_product',
      'foreign_field' => 'product',
      'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
      'maxitems' => 9999,
      'appearance' => [
         'collapseAll' => 0,
         'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
         'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
         'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
         'useSortable' => 1,
         'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1,
      ],
   ],
],
```

Any idea of how to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the sorting for the whole table is enabled in the `'ctrl'` defintion of the table. It shall be not if you also want to change the sorting for inline elements of the same table. Check out the warning inside the official docs: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#foreign-sortby

Comment: Thanks! But Product is the 'Main' Domain that should be sortable. If i disable sorting in the ctrl it isn´t sortable anymore

Answer (score 0):

When you need different sorting for the same sub products over different main products, 1:n with the original sorting field of the target table is not an option.

You should go for an MM table instead or even use an intermedate table as described in the IRRE tutorial.